# How to get props passed through Route using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

> Here are the Routes in App.js

```
 <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route  path='/dashboard'
       render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} isAuthed={true} />} />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

> How to access isAuthed in Dashboard component. Either using lifecycle
>   or directly assig to state in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case. If you want to **further mutate** the passed prop, you can use a lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate`. Directly assigning the props to the state inside the `constructor` is considered a bad practice, you can directly use the props using `this.props.isAuthed`.

Note that, when using a lifecycle method, it's essential to ensure that you do not constantly re-render your component. The following approach might come in handy.

```
state = {
  isAuthed: false
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevProps.isAuthed !== this.props.isAuthed) {
     this.setState({ isAuthed: this.props.isAuthed });
  }
}
```

By only allowing the state to be mutated when `isAuthed` changes, you can reduce the amount of re-renders. Or, an easier method as explained above, if you donot want to mutate the props, you can use props directly.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {       console.log(nextProps.isAuthed);      }                                               Is this correct method ?

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur, `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated, use componentDidUpdate instead.

Comment: Okay I will try. Thanks

Comment: setState in componentDidUpdate causes an extra render (not directly perceptible to user but it slows down your app). And you render method can’t assume the state is ready (because it won’t be the first time). That's the reason why we need to use `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: `setState` is only called when the prop changes, hence the check. Also, `componentDidUpdate` is only called when an update happens, otherwise it won't be called at all.  And it slows down the app, how so? can you give an example.

Comment: Also, setState is being called behind the scenes inside `getDerivedStateFromProps`, well, it's called for each subsequent update. Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle instead. Which method is best for your use case this is all upto you bro.

Comment: Yes, that's the case, a simpler alternative would be not using a lifecycle method at all. Simply accessing the props using `this.props` is enough as I mentioned, `getDerivedStateFromProps` is definitely not a handy enough approach for this use case. Probably overkill since it will be called for each subsequent update. Hence, the alternative `componentDidUpdate` which will **only** be called when a change happens as compared to ``getDerived`` which is called on initial render as well and on all subsequent updates which is simply not necessary. @ClueMediator

Answer (score 0):

From react [blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html), 16.3 introduced depreciation notices for `componentWillRecieveProps`.

I would suggest you to use `static getDerivedStateFromProps` method to handle the `isAuthed` prop.

Following code is used to update the `isAuthed` state variable based on the props.

```
state = {
  isAuthed: this.props.isAuthed
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (nextProps.isAuthed !== prevState.isAuthed) {
    return ({ isAuthed: nextProps.isAuthed}) // <- this is setState equivalent
  }
  etc...
}
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Deriving state leads to verbose code and makes your components difficult to think about, simpler alternative would be ``componendDidUpdate``.

Comment: If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead. Which method is best for your use case this is all upto you bro.